# Client and Server in same app to send and then receive Bytes

Tags: java, android, sockets

I trying to replace a Bluetooth connection with a WiFi one. My original project has a PIC Microcontroller that is data logging time, date and temps as well as controlling some outputs. I wrote an app quite a while ago (3 years, and done none since!) that uses Bluetooth to send and receive data from Android to the PIC, works fine. 
So far I've got a ESP8266 connected to a Pic Microcontroller, the ESP is using ESP-LINK firmware and is connected to my home network. The pic relays what is received from the ESP8266 to RealTerm so I can monitor. I've created a test app which is creating a socket and sending a byte to the PIC, which is working fine and the bytes are being received ok, code as below.

```
package com.example.carl.sockets;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 23;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "00.00.00.00"; // enter IP of ESP8266 here

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            if(i > 0 && i < 255){
                out.write(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Number out of Range !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the byte is sent to the PIC it will send a Byte or Bytes back as a response. I now need to read the byte or bytes returned from the PIC and display them in a TextView. I will know how many bytes will be sent by the PIC and received by the app in advance.

I've looked at loads of code but all seem to be for separate servers and clients, and I don't want that (or do I) and can't figure this one out.

This has probably been asked before but I've spent ages looking, and any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've now got this working and can send a byte and receive either a single byte or bytes from my PIC via WiFi to my android app.
I've created a new thread to wait for data on the input stream. My main issue was ensuring the socket was connected before starting this thread, once I had sussed that it has worked ok.
When data is received it's sent back to the main code via a handler. My handler is outputting text to my app depending what is received, the seven bytes are a temp reading and time and date. The single byte is just displayed.
My code is attached which may not be pretty !! any constructive criticism would be welcome.

```
package com.example.carl.sockets;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Main Activity - Sockets";
    private Handler h;
    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 23;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.78"; // enter IP of ESP8266 here
    private receiveData rd;
    protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
    protected static final int NOW_DATA_RECEIVED = 1;
    protected static final int ONE_BYTE_RECEIVED = 2;
    private boolean connectedSocket = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

        while(!connectedSocket){}

        rd = new receiveData(socket);
        rd.start();

    h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                        break;
                    case NOW_DATA_RECEIVED:
                        Log.d(TAG,"Handler - In 7 bytes received");
                        byte[] nowData = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        // process data
                        int tempFrac = 0;
                        int tempUnits = 0;
                        // construct time and date string, pad to 2 figures, unsigned values
                        String hourStr = Integer.toString(nowData[2]&0xFF);
                        hourStr = "00".substring(hourStr.length()) + hourStr;
                        String minStr = Integer.toString(nowData[3]&0xFF);
                        minStr = "00".substring(minStr.length()) + minStr;
                        String dayStr = Integer.toString(nowData[4]&0xFF);
                        dayStr = "00".substring(dayStr.length()) + dayStr;
                        String monthStr = Integer.toString(nowData[5]&0xFF);
                        monthStr = "00".substring(monthStr.length()) + monthStr;
                        String yearStr = Integer.toString(nowData[6]&0xFF);
                        yearStr = "00".substring(yearStr.length()) + yearStr;
                        String nowDataString = new String(hourStr +":" + minStr + " " + dayStr + "/" + monthStr + "/" + yearStr);
                        // get unsigned values
                        int tempMSB = nowData[0] & 0xFF;
                        int tempLSB = nowData[1] & 0xFF;
                        // add LSB and MSB
                        int tempVar = tempLSB + (tempMSB<<8);
                        // if Zero
                        if(tempVar == 0){
                            // result zero so display zero degrees
                            // put in text view
                            TextView txtData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                            txtData.setText(nowDataString + " Temp = 0.0c");
                        }else if(tempMSB >= 0x80){
                            // result negative
                            tempVar = (~tempVar) + 1;
                            tempFrac = tempVar & 0x0F;
                            tempFrac = tempFrac*625/1000;
                            tempUnits = (tempVar>>4)&0x7F;
                            String tempString = new String("-"+Integer.toString(tempUnits)+"."+Integer.toString(tempFrac));
                            // put in text view
                            TextView txtData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                            txtData.setText(nowDataString + " Temp = " + tempString + "c");
                        }else{
                            // result positive
                            tempFrac = tempVar & 0x0F;
                            tempFrac = tempFrac*625/1000;
                            tempVar = tempVar>>4;
                            tempUnits = tempVar & 0x7F;
                            String tempString = new String(Integer.toString(tempUnits)+"."+Integer.toString(tempFrac));
                            // put in text view
                            TextView txtData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                            txtData.setText(nowDataString + " Temp = " + tempString + "c");
                        }
                        break;
                    case ONE_BYTE_RECEIVED:
                        Log.d(TAG,"Handler - In 1 byte received");
                        byte[] recByte = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        int receivedByte = (int)recByte[0];
                        TextView txtData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        txtData.setText( "One Byte Received = " + Integer.toString(receivedByte));
                        Log.d(TAG, "In handler, one byte received = "+ Integer.toString(receivedByte));
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        try{
            socket.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.d(TAG,"Error closing socket in on pause");
        }
        rd.stopRdThread();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            if (i > 0 && i < 255) {
                out.write(i);
                Log.d(TAG,"Byte Sending - "+ i.toString());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Number out of Range !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                if(socket.isConnected()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "in ClientThread - socket connected");
                    connectedSocket = true;
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "in ClientThread - socket not connected");
                    connectedSocket = false;
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class receiveData extends Thread {
        private Socket socketLocal;
        private volatile boolean exit = false;
        DataInputStream in;
        byte[] fullBuffer = new byte[7];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
        int bytesCount = 0;

        // constructor
        receiveData(Socket socket){
            this.socketLocal = socket;
        }

        public void run(){
            try {
                if (socketLocal.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In receiveData, Socket connected");
                    in = new DataInputStream(socketLocal.getInputStream());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "in receiveData - run exception - " + e.toString());
            }

            while(!exit){
                try {
                    if (socketLocal.isConnected()) {
                        if (in.available() > 0) {
                            //input = in.readByte();     // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                            bytes = in.read(buffer);
                            Log.d(TAG,"Bytes Read = "+Integer.toString(bytes));
                            System.arraycopy(buffer,0,fullBuffer,bytesCount,bytes);
                            bytesCount = bytesCount + bytes;
                            if(bytesCount >= 7){
                                h.obtainMessage(NOW_DATA_RECEIVED, bytesCount, -1, fullBuffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                                Log.d(TAG,"In handler, 7 bytes Message sent");
                                bytesCount = 0;
                            }else if(bytesCount == 1){
                                h.obtainMessage(ONE_BYTE_RECEIVED, bytesCount, -1, fullBuffer).sendToTarget();
                                Log.d(TAG, "In handler, 1 byte message sent");
                                bytesCount = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Read Error - " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        public void stopRdThread(){
            exit = true;
            try {
                socketLocal.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "error closing socket - " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only issue I now have is a memory leak, I think ?
I'm getting a message -
07-30 17:46:01.154 15417-15445/com.example.carl.sockets D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 22% free 9692K/12332K, paused 18ms, total 18ms

The monitor is showing I'm using 9.4 MB once the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the leak, it was the `in.available()` that I was using to test if data is there for some reason. Don't really understand that! Got rid of the two `if()` statements in the receiveData and it works great now.